# Why is this question being downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Why is https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/should-we-love-jesus-enemies [currently at -2] being down voted?

- Is it due to being close to "pastoral advice"?
- Is it due to being potentially divisive in marking certain people as Christ's "enemies" ?

In more pragmatic matters, I've been curious about this matter myself:

- for example, should Biblical Christians post articles explaining how JW is heretical for denying the deity of Christ?
- furthermore, is it Christian to preach Christ yet sit on one of the world's biggest bank accounts? Why do both the Momon/Catholic ministries have far more material wealth than Christ / his 11 disciples ever did?

And it seems like question being asked by the poster is along similar lines.

Comment: both of the example questions you propose here (in the phrasings presented) would be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was downvoted (and is now closed) because it runs counter to one of the major foundations that this site is run on.

**Anyone who claims to be a Christian, for the purpose of this site, and questions posed on it, is considered to be a Christian**

Identifying groups that consider themselves to be Christians as "Jesus' Enemies" is not something that we look kindly on (whether or not we as moderators or users agree). These posts are, and should be down voted, flagged, closed and/or deleted (by the community, or in rare cases moderators), if they do happen to contain a nugget of usefulness then perhaps a timely edit and reopen might help. However, posts that attempt to disparage other sects should be dealt with quickly and decisively.

No matter what you, I, or others who post on this site believe. It does us no good to disparage people who we welcome to this site with questions like this. No one is asking that you embrace anything that you consider heresy, just that it not be disparaged on this site.

Comment: [Christianity.SE vs. Survivor](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/132) provides a lot of the history behind this decision. This is part of the SEI mandate for this site (Hedge was an SEI employee when she wrote that).